# Instantiate another class in sealed class

Tags: c#, .net

What is the recommended way to instantiate another class inside a sealed class:

```
public sealed class AvayaService
{
    private static Lazy<AvayaService> lazy =
       new Lazy<AvayaService>(() => new AvayaService());

    public static AvayaService AvayaServiceInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!lazy.IsValueCreated)
                lazy = new Lazy<AvayaService>(() => new AvayaService());
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    private AvayaService()
    {
    }

    public static Response GetResponse(Request request)
    {
       var _repository = new Repository(); //  what is the best way to get the instance here

    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
   ...
}
```

I am trying to learn sealed class and lazy instantiation however I am pondering over what should be the recommended way to instantiate another class in a sealed class?

Comment: `sealed` means that you cannot inherit from it. I am not sure how `sealed` is at all related to your code

Comment: you are instantiating stuff in side static functions. As stated by @CamiloTerevinto this has nothing to do with the sealed keyword.

Comment: The way to instantiate a new class is with the `new` keyword. This is true regardless of where the code is running: inside a sealed class, inside an unsealed class, inside a static method, inside whatever. The only time you wouldn't use the `new` keyword is if you are using Reflection.

Comment: static functions can be called anywhere. -- Unlike member functions which must be called on the instantiated object

Comment: @JohnWu Or when using Dependency Injection...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I realize you are splitting hairs, so let me split them further. If you are writing a class that consumes an injected object, your code should not instantiate anything. If you are using an IoC container or a serivce locator, the container or locator is using `new` or Reflection  under the covers. So ultimately those are the only ways. Except... since we're splitting hairs... you could theoretically call [GetUninitializedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) too. May be over OP's head.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no "recommendations" in this area. If you've read recommendations, read again, most probably it was just an exercise. It gives you an idea, but using this idea in a real project is up to you. Sometimes those exercises demonstrate an opposite approaches. Sometimes the repository owner will dictate the style which is against of any rules you've read before, and it's totally fine.

Here's another instantiation exercise which I think is helpful to try: to never instantiate anything except value objects. Delegate instantiation to a [container](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx). Avoid singleton pattern, but register your service as a singleton in your container. In this way your code will look like:

```
public sealed class AvayaService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public AvayaService(IRepository repository)
    {
        if(repository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public static Response GetResponse(Request request)
    {
        // use _repository
    }
}
```